# How to find Duplicate values in the sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have four Excel sheets where i am having Movies list. i want to compare fourth sheet with first three sheets and need to write only common movies into a text file.or can say in next sheet.

Comment: Do you need a Formula or VBA Code?

Comment: Quick question. What do you mean by common? Common in all 3 sheets or if the movie from the 4th sheet is found even in one of the sheets (1 - 3) then it should get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the following. Please change as applicable.

1) All values are in the 1st column

2) Sheet Names are "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3" and "Sheet4"

3) Output has to be written to a text file called Sample.txt in C:

4) You will take care of Error handling.

**TRIED AND TESTED**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    Dim Ar() As String, strSearch As String, FlName As String
    Dim filesize As Integer

    '~~> Set your sheets here
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet3")
    Set ws4 = Sheets("Sheet4")

    '~~> Get LastRow of sheet 4
    LastRow = ws4.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    n = 0

    '~~> Loop through cells in Sheet4 to get the value to compare
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        strSearch = ws4.Range("A" & i).Value

        '~~> Check Sheets 1,2 and 3
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws1.Columns(1), strSearch) > 0 Then
            '~~> Store it in an array
            n = n + 1: ReDim Preserve Ar(n): Ar(n) = strSearch
        ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws2.Columns(1), strSearch) > 0 Then
            n = n + 1: ReDim Preserve Ar(n): Ar(n) = strSearch
        ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws3.Columns(1), strSearch) > 0 Then
            n = n + 1: ReDim Preserve Ar(n): Ar(n) = strSearch
        End If
    Next i

    '~~> Write to Text File. Change path as applicable
    FlName = "C:\Sample.Txt"

    '~~> Get a free file handle
    filesize = FreeFile()

    '~~> Open your file
    Open FlName For Output As #filesize

    '~~> Export Text
    For i = 1 To UBound(Ar)
        Print #filesize, Ar(i)
    Next i

    Close #filesize
End Sub
```